# Launch one activity from another with an item value

Tags: android, android-activity, arrays

I have a ListActivity:

```
public class MedTime extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.no_elements_l);

      String[] receipts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.receipts_array);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, receipts));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
```

I'd like: when user clicks on list item, new activity named "view" launches. In addition, i need to say to this "view" activity which element from list called it. For example, if I click to 3rd element of list, activity "view" must be started and show me text  = 3rd element of string array. The code fragment of "view" is here (value of i in last line must be sent by main activity to this, in my example i=3):

```
String[] receipts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.receipts_array);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(receipts[i]);
```

Please, tell me how to 1) launch "view" activity when user click a list item; 2) how to launch in this case "view" with the parameter that describes number of item selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the item position to your intent and start the new activity.

```
....
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(MedTime.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("item", position);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the activity you started, extract the item in onCreate() from the intent.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

int id = intent.getIntExtra("item", -1);

if (id != -1) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received item: " + id);
}
```

After this I can't say what you wanna do. One possibility is to get the string value from your array as.

```
String[] receipts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.receipts_array);
String myItem = receipts[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

third parameter "position" is clicked item position starts from zero .
what else u need ??